# Changing jQuery spectrum color palette after initializing?

Tags: jquery, spectrum

I'm using jQuery Spectrum as a color picker in my app (http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum). I can't figure out how to set the palette after the plugin has been initialized.

This how I create a palette when it's first initialized:

```
$("#showPalette").spectrum({
    showPalette: true,
    palette: [
        ['black', 'white', 'blanchedalmond'],
        ['rgb(255, 128, 0);', 'hsv 100 70 50', 'lightyellow']
    ]
});
```

How could I update the palette to a new selection of colors without destroying and re-initializing?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saw that no one has responded to this yet so I'd thought I give it a try.    The short answer is that it is possible to change almost anything once it is in the DOM.   I created a simple demo here to show the color palette initialized and then dynamically added (and removed) a color to the palette.

Hope this helps.

[jsfiddle code demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kaiHogan/uuvpZ/)

```
$("#colorTest").spectrum({
    showPalette: true,
    flat: true,
    palette: [
        ['black', 'white', 'blanchedalmond'],
        ['rgb(255, 128, 0);', 'hsv 100 70 50', 'lightyellow']
    ]
});

$('#add').click( function() {
    var newColor = "<span id='colorRed' title='red' data-color='red' class='sp-thumb-el sp-thumb-light'><sp class='sp-thumb-inner' style='background-color: red;'></span></span>";

    if ( $("[data-color='red']").length == 0 ) {
       $(newColor).appendTo('.sp-palette-row-0');
    }
});

$('#remove').click( function() {
   $('#colorRed').remove();
});
```

Comment: I never noticed this answer so accepting more than 1 year later! Indeed this works :)